# Manager operation results: Applied | Backtracked | Failed | Skipped

Tags: operation

`Applied` is self explanatory but the others really arent.  The source code gives a bit of clues though; as file [apply_results.mli](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/mainnet/src/proto_006_PsCARTHA/lib_protocol/apply_results.mli) says

> [Skipped] ones should always be at the tail, and after a single
> [Failed]

So in which cases would failed be used over backtracked, and vice-versa?  And will we always have guaranteed atomicity on the entire group of transactions in an operation?

Comment: Just a guess, but say we have transactions A that generated internal transactions B C and D. If C, fails, then C is Failed, A and B are Backtracked and D is Skipped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is pretty simple:

- `failed` - operations which failed with some particular error (not enough balance, gas limit, etc);
- `backtracked` - operations which were successful but reverted due to one of the following operations in the same operation group was failed;
- `skipped` - all the operations after the failed one.

However, after `Babylon` update some errors cause the operation to be marked as `backtracked`, but not `failed`. For example, [when sender can't pay allocation fee](https://tzkt.io/ooyynpmcUE1wPUWatxZxqk3Nnwao7NxteZZfnPW2YRkEWeQMQyj).

So, it looks like this:

```
Operation group:
  backtracked
  backtracked
  backtracked
  failed (or backtracked)    <-- here is the actual error
  skipped
  skipped
  skipped
```

And yes, all operations in the same operation group are atomic.