# Manager operation results: failed, backtracked, skipped

Tags: operation, fees

When a manager operation result's status is one of the in the title mentioned what exactly does that mean?

Do the fees still get payed to the baker, or are they also canceled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** `failed` is the operation of the batch that failed, `skipped` are operations in the batch which  were not executed, and `backtracked` are those operations preceding the failing op which whose effects were backtracked. The fees for the whole batch are still taken from the signer of the batch -- *"the manager"* -- and payed to the baker.

In the current semantics of the Tezos economic protocol, the execution of a batch of manager operations has an *"all or nothing"* semantics[*], meaning that a batch of manager operations which is included in a block only takes effect if and only if all of the operations in the batch succeed.

The execution (in Tezos protocol jargon, the "application") of a batch of manager operations is done in the sequential order they appear in the batch.

When this iteration encounters that the application of an operation fails, it will mark that operation as `failed`, and skip the application of the tail of the batch (which will have every operation marked as `skipped`)

If the failing operation was preceded by successfully applied ones, say that the failing operation is in the middle, the effect of that prefix will be backtracked (and each operation in that prefix will be marked as `backtracked`).

Thus say there is 5 operations in a bach, and the one in the middle fails, the batch will be have a prefix of 2 backtracked operations, followed by a single falling one, followed by a tail with 2 skipped operations.

If a batch of manager operations can be included in a block, the fees are taken for the whole batch, *regardless of the outcome of the application of the operation*.

[*]: Or, at least they should. There is one corner-case (see [tezos/tezos#2386](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/2386)) that breaks this semantics and is currently being reworked.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in previous questions.

[Manager operation results: Applied | Backtracked | Failed | Skipped](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/manager-operation-results-applied-backtracked-failed-skipped)

About costs (the fees still go to the baker): [What happens to the fee of a rejected transaction?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/3662/what-happens-to-the-fee-of-a-rejected-transaction)